# How to pass int as a parameter in @selector method

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way which I can pass a simple integer parameter to `@selector` method. Please share your one liner code which I can try. I have tried using sender and tag but that is not working as expected, instead I would prefer to just pass the `int` value as parameter and collect in the method call.

I just want to pass this integer value to function called on action of button, i dont want to use sender id etc. Any other approaches please let me know.

```
static int i=1;
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(removeTextField:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: please explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish with this piece of code. your wording is unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want a way to track which button was clicked. In that case, the simplest way is really to set the tag of the button to your integer:

```
button.tag = 1;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(removeTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

and then retrieve the tag via the sender:

```
-(IBAction) removeTextField:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    NSLog(@"%d",button.tag); // an NSInteger
}
```

There are other workarounds such as subclassing UIButton, but they mostly require substantial amount of work.

Comment: I am clear with set and get tag, my requirement is to pass the int value function called and retired in function definition.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass arguments via selector. You can however create an INT as your class property and access it from any method within your class. Meaning you can set it in the same method as you have your selector and then access it in the method your selector points to.

Alternatively you could set the button's tag to the value you need and pass that as your int but that is probably not the best way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You should convert int to NSUInteger or NSNumber.

```
 NSNumber* iParam = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
```

get int value back:

```
int i = [iParam intValue];
```

Comment: Or use String Literals (?) to shorten the conversion: @(i)